# not saving post in wp_post wordpress database table

Tags: database

I write following code to save post in wordoress wp_post database table.

but don't save in database

```
  function writeMsg(){
     global $wpdb;
     $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp_farsc" );
     $data = null;
   $data.= '<table border="2px" cellspacing="5px" width="100%">'.PHP_EOL;
   $data.= '<tr bgcolor="yellow"><th>سکه</th><th>قیمت انلاین</th><th>تغییر قیمت</th><th>کمترین</th><th>بیشترین</th><th>زمان بروز رسانی</th></tr>'.PHP_EOL;

   foreach ( $result as $row ) {

      $data .='<tr>';
      $data .= '<td>'.$row-> titile.'</td>';
      $data .='<td>'.$row -> liveprice.'</td>';
      $data .='<td>'.$row -> changing.'</td>';
      $data .= '<td>'.$row-> lowest.'</td>';
      $data .= '<td>'.$row-> topest.'</td>';
      $data .= '<td>'.$row-> time.'</td>';
      $data .='</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
   }
 return $data;
 }
 $oiobz1 = writeMsg(1, 'center', '', 1);

function importposts() {
    $postdate = date('2014-06-19 00:30:00');
    $postdate_gmt = date('2014-06-19 04:30:00');
    $titles=' 111111111111111111111111111';
    $posts = array(
        'post_content'   => $oiobz1,
        'post_name'      => $titles,
        'post_title'     => $titles,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_author'    => '1',
        'ping_status'    => 'publish',
        'to_ping'        => 'http://rpc.pingomatic.com/',
        'post_date_gmt'  => $postdate_gmt,
        'post_date'  => $postdate,
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($posts);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'META-KEY-1', 'META_VALUE-1', true);
} 


  ?>
```

Comment: where do you call `importposts`?

Comment: Nowhere.........  @Milo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Milo noted, you need to call the importposts functions to have it do anything.

Additionally, if your post is not inserted, post_id should hold a wp_error object, so you could see what is wrong by doing the following right before add_post_meta

```
if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
   echo "<p>Bad Post Attempt:</p><pre>" . print_r($post_id, true) . "</pre>";
}
```

That should point to any problem with your query provided you call the function and there is a query.

Calling the function... (just in case)

After you create your function, it needs to be called:

```
importposts();
```

Personally, I'd give it a more distinct name ... and you probably need to wrap call it via an action that occurs sometime after wordpress has loaded

```
function do_my_import_posts_now() {
   importposts();
}
add_action('wp', 'do_my_import_posts_now');
```

That will ensure that wordpress is set up before your function is called.